# Dynamic controls in PDF Adobe Cycle

Tags: forms, pdf, livecycle

Does anyone know how to add control (example: field) on-run in PDF? I'm using Adobe LiveCycle ES2; need that piece of JavaScript....

Thank you all -

Answer (score 0):

I previously tried to do something similar but have never been able to find a method of dynamically creating an object on a form.
You can use the addInstance command to add an instance of a new form and it's possible to add additional rows to a table but other than that, the only method I have found that works is to add the objects from the toolbox and then show/hide them.
It does mean that you're adding additional objects to the form but if used correctly this doesn't really have too much affect on the file size but it does involve extra coding.